# WPF in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

**Hi guys,**

I'm working on new project that based on Windows Forms C# pattern.
One of the window in my software, need to be designed by WPF, is there any way to use WPF window inside Windows Forms project?

I mean, when i'm calling to new window i use this code:

```
Windows w = new Windows();
w.Show();
```

but when i'm trying to it on the WPF class it's throwing me an error that it's not supported.

Can i do something like that with the WPF window?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can use the entire window, but you can definitely host a wpf control inside WinForms. Take a look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

Comment: You can use ElementHost control to host a WPF control on a WinForms form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open WPF window in WindowsForm APP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311956/open-wpf-window-in-windowsform-app)

Comment: `I'm working on new project that based on Windows Form` - winforms is not recommended for any new projects. Only to maintain legacy applications. forget winforms and create the entire application in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore you are right. now when i am thinking about it, my choice to use winforms was bad. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find yourself in need to open a WPF Window from a WinForms program:

1. Create/Add a new project of type "WPF Custom Control Library"
2. Add a new Item of type "Window (WPF)"
3. Do your thing with the WPF Window
4. From your WinForms app, create and open the WPF Window.

code snippet:

```
WPFWindow.Window1 wpfwindow = new WPFWindow.Window1();
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow);
wpfwindow.Show();
```

However ensure you have the following using statements:

```
using System; //Given 
using System.Windows.Forms; //Given
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration; //Not so Given.
```

Refer:
[How to programmatically create a WPF window in a WinForm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874495/how-to-programmatically-create-a-wpf-window-in-a-winform-application)
[Open a WPF Window from WinForms & link form app with WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511382/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms-link-form-app-with-wpf-app)
[How to add a WPF window to a WinForms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142814/how-to-add-a-wpf-window-to-a-winforms-app)

Comment: Note: you must add the assembly WindowsFormsIntegration to your project in order to have the System.Windows.Forms.Integration namespace. It's not where you expect to see it since it doesn't have the "." format like the rest of the assemblies do.

Comment: Second Note: You probably will want to center your WPF window over the Winform window. This site shows how: https://jiezhao.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/how-to-set-winform-as-the-owner-of-wpf-window/